# On scroll animation issue on small screens using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, animate-on-scroll

I’ve created an animation for my website to change a certain element (for example its background colour) while scrolling using Vanilla JS. For this I have used the `window.onscroll` property and I trigger the animation when `window.scrollY` reaches a specific position, my code is:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   if (window.scrollX >= 1000) {
      box.style = "background:red"
   }
})
```

It looks great when I am editing on my big screen resolution, but if I look at the page on my laptop, the animation gets messed up because the `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` of the screen are different. I want to trigger the animation dynamically if it reaches a certain section of the page without having to worry about the scroll position.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can fix this?

Comment: try searching on "javascript dynamic inner height and width"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957633/how-can-i-dynamically-get-browser-height-and-width/47957703

Answer (score 0):

I think using `getBoundingClientRect()` solves your problem.
You basically do something like this:

```
var my_box = document.getElementById('my-box');
var rect = my_box.getBoundingClientRect();
```

The `rect` variable now contains an Object which includes a `top` and a `left` property with values that are relative to the viewport.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect